# can't drop MySQL table if exist and create new one Note: #1051 Unknown table

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Can't drop table if exist and create new table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Persons`;

CREATE TABLE Persons (
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255) 
);

INSERT INTO Persons (LastName, FirstName, Address, City)
VALUES ('Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '4006');
```

Note: #1051 Unknown table 'ff.persons' 
finally, insert query is getting

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0485 seconds.)

[image: please see this]

Comment: Its not an error, here you are getting Note from DB that the table is not exists hence it is not dropped.

Comment: But the problem is It skip one query. Wordpress database has 50 queries default. in here 49 queries are executed and the website didn't t load correctly

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code and the previous table was dropped when run the code,
don't worry this is normal way, it didn't return anything. That is normal for an INSERT, as it isn't a SELECT query and as such doesn't specify anything to return, so it doesn't return anything.

Comment: But the problem is It skip one query. Wordpress database has 50 queries default. in here 49 queries are executed and the website didn't t load correctly